# PHP Silex: Why my queryBuilder is wrong?

Tags: php, sql, silex, query-builder

I don't know why my querybuilder is wrong...

```
$sunday = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("next sunday", time())); 
$monday = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("last monday", time())); 


$maxPerPage = $request->get('perpage',5);

$currentPage = $request->get('page',1);

$conn = $app['dbs']['basket'];

$queryBuilder = new QueryBuilder($conn);

$queryBuilder
->select('fu.*, f.name as feedname')
->from('feed_urls', 'fu')
->leftJoin('fu', 'feeds', 'f', 'f.id = fu.feed_id')
->where('fu.modified <= :identifier')
->andWhere('fu.modified >= :identifier2')
->andWhere('fu.hits >= 1')
->orderBy("fu.hits","DESC")
->setParameter('identifier',  $sunday)
->setParameter('identifier2',  $monday)
->setMaxResults( $maxPerPage );

$basket_list = $conn->executeQuery($queryBuilder);
$basket_list = $basket_list->fetchAll();
```

**Error**

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':identifier) AND (fu.modified >= :identifier2) AND (fu.hits >= 1) ORDER BY fu.hi' at line 1
```

**Note**

If I don't use **setParameter**, works fine!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
->setParameter(':identifier',  $sunday)
->setParameter(':identifier2',  $monday)
```

Edit

```
->where('fu.modified <= ?1')
->setParameter(1,  $sunday)
->andWhere('fu.modified >= ?2')
->setParameter(2,  $monday)
->andWhere('fu.hits >= 1')
->orderBy("fu.hits","DESC")
```

Also check if $monday and $sunday are set.